# Why doesn't Teradata identity column increment by 1?

Tags: teradata

I have the following table

```
CREATE SET TABLE myTab,FALLBACK,NO BEFORE JOURNAL,NO AFTER JOURNAL,CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
     (
      my_id BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
           (START WITH 1 
            INCREMENT BY 1 
            MINVALUE 1 
            MAXVALUE 922337203685477580 
            NO CYCLE),
      created_by VARCHAR(200) )
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( my_id );
```

When I started insetring into this table (`INSERT INTO myTab (created_by) VALUES ('test')`, here are the values for `my_id` that got auto generated

```
my_id
1
100,001
100,002
200,001
300,001
400,001
500,001
500,002
600,001
```

I was looking to get 1,2,3 . . . incremented by 1. I read the [teradata explanation](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1184_111A/Create_Table-Details.012.045.html) but still don't understand. Why does it increment by a random number ? This way I will reach the `MAXVALUE 922337203685477580` pretty soon. What will happen then ?

Comment: Even if that thing counted by millions (It's counting by one hundred thousand here) and never iterated at a smaller number than one million you wouldn't run out of numbers. Like... even counting by 1 million you have 1 trillion numbers to go through still.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. But I still don't understand why is it doing this ? If it's incrementing by 100K now, who know it might start incrementing by 100B tomorrow. How does Teradata determine the increment value ? Is it random ?

Comment: Also what is the use of `INCREMENT BY 1`  . . . does this command (if you will) make any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the explanation you are seeking can be found in the SQL Data Definition Language - Detailed Topics under Chapter 5: Create Table, [Process for Generating Identity Column Numbers](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1184_111A/Create_Table-Details.012.046.html). Identity columns are not intended to provide an accurate, sequential order for which the rows are loaded into a table.

If you want a sequential identifier, you will have to maintain that yourself in your ETL with a combination of the max value in the table plus the `ROW_NUMBER()` assigned to the data set you are loading into the table. Otherwise, you may want to reconsider whether a sequence id/row num is actually required in your implementation.